# StackExchange Data Explorer understanding the Bounty Award Counts

Tags: discussion, bounty, data-explorer

I saw this guy score a 2nd bounty on [his own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178167/reading-a-single-channel-from-a-multi-channel-wav-file/), it was a 500 pointer from Madara Uchiha taking the tally to **700**:

[image: Answer with 700 bounty reputation points]

I checked the [bounty award counts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/5400/bounty-award-counts) and nothing goes over 550:

[image: Bounty award counts]

I can't work out why this guy's 700 point bounty is not showing in Jon Seigel's SQL query. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a 700 rep bounty. The post had two bounties, one for 200 rep & one for 500 rep.

Comment: How did 97 people get 550?

Comment: That was back from the early days when bounties were first introduced, the machine added 50 promotional points.